# Customizing UILabels colors in custom cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am using a custom cell in my TableView with a few UILabels. I need to change their colour when they are selected/highlighted.

1) Should I use tableviewWillDisplayCell: ?
2) How to differentiate the selected/highlighted cell in it?

Comment: Are you customizing your cell using a nib file, or subclassing UITableViewCell?

Comment: It's a nib file...containing the customized cell.
I am accessing the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath: using
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([CustomCell class])
                                              owner:nil
                                            options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything about discovering the highlighting/selection. A UITableViewCell automatically highlights all of its subviews (the ones that *can* be highlighted) when it is selected. A UILabel *is* a view that can be highlighted; that is, it has a `highlighted` property and it responds automatically to being highlighted.

So there is no work for you to do; you're over-thinking the problem. Just set each label's `highlightedTextColor` property and everything will happen automatically. As another answer points out, you can do this right in the nib, or you can do it in code.

If you do need to do something special when a cell is selected, the simplest way is to use a UITableViewCell subclass and override `setSelected:animated:`. But there doesn't seem to be any need for this in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the highlight color of your UILabel on your nib. Select the label on the interface editor and on the right panel you should find an option to change the highlighted color (I'm not on a Mac so can't give more precise instructions).

If you can't find it, just change the color on your code. I assume you change the text of that label using something like this:

```
myLabel.text = @"something";
```

Just set the highlightedTextColor:

```
myLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score -1):

first things first, are you able to see your cell in the right way? if you did create a custom cell i would go with this:

```
    // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCustomCell";

        MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


        if (cell == nil) { 
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell"
                                                 owner:self options:nil];
            for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[MyCustomCell class]])
        cell = (MyCustomCell *)oneObject;
        } 

        // Set up the cell
        //...

        return cell;
    }
```

Now regarding your questions,

1-) I Use the method *tableviewWillDisplayCell* when i have to work the background of the uitableviewcell so this might not be what you're looking for

2-) If you select a specific tableViewCell it will be selected (by default it will leave it blue), so if you just want to select the last selected cell, you just need to use this:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //...

    // do your stuff
```

}

if you want to use your highlight methods for your custom appearance you'll have to add 
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; 
to your *didSelectRowAtIndexPath* and then change the UI of the tableViewCell. Also if you want to save wich cell has been selected you can save the indexPath.row in a data structure such as a NSMutableArray and you would have to do that operation in the *didSelectRowAtIndexPath* method

hope this helps, if you need any further help, let me know!

Jorge